# Need Help for a political terms- calling back MPs

Tags: single-word-requests, politics

Some political systems allow voters to 'call back' an MP mid-term if he/she doesn't perform up to their expectations. What is the formal political term used for such process ?

Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: Please confirm that you mean MP (Member of Parliament) rather than PM (Prime Minister). (Perhaps it was a typo on your part?) Your question makes more sense (it will be easier to answer) if you intended to ask it in the context of a PM (Prime Minister) rather than a constituency MP. There are answers to cover both MP and/or PM  but we shall need to know confirmation that your OP did intend MP. It would also help me to answer your OP in either case if we knew which country and its political system you had in mind. Would that be the UK (Great Britain)?

Comment: In Britain such a procedure was introduced for the first time in the [*Recall of MPs Act* 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recall_of_MPs_Act_2015)

Answer (score 1):

That would be a [recall election.](http://Recall%20election) From wikipedia:

> A recall election (also called a **recall referendum** or **representative
>   recall**) is a procedure by which voters can remove an elected official
>   from office through a direct vote before his or her term has ended.